# how can I change the scrollbar location once a link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button on my index.html page like this:

About Us

and once the user has clicked this button and been moved to the About Us page, I want to position the scrollbar around 200px down from the top of the page. I saw a few questions on SO about how to move the page down using a jQuery plugin. However, I want to be able to first navigate to the new page, and then automatically scroll the page down for the user. My first thought was to have some jQuery that would just move the About Us page down on page-load. However, I only want the page to move down only when the link on my index page is clicked and not if a user navigates to the page from another way. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an element on the `about us` page with an ID you can change your link to (note that the forward slash is not before the id).

`<a href="about.html#ElementID"/>`

and that will put the scroll point to the element with that ID. For example, this link will bring you back to this

[This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28467667/how-can-i-change-the-scrollbar-location-once-a-link-is-clicked#answers) -  `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28467667/how-can-i-change-the-scrollbar-location-once-a-link-is-clicked#answers`

Will bring you to this page but set the scroll to the answers form.

If this isn't the method you want to use you can always try this Javascript

```
function ScrollPoint() { 
  var PageHeight=document.body.clientHeight;
  var params = window.location.search.substr(1).split('&');
  for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
    var a=params[i].split('=');
    if (a[0] == 'scroll') {
        // Add Validation the urlParam (0-9) only! Validation is good!
      var urlParam= decodeURIComponent(a[1]);
      var ScrollPoint=PageHeight-urlParam;
    window.scroll(0, ScrollPoint);
    }
  }

}
window.onload=ScrollPoint;
```

You could set a parameter in the url /?scroll=200 and use javascript to check for a scoll= parameter, if the scroll param is set then this will scroll to that point.

I hope this helps, happy coding!

Comment: that method works. however, in my About Us page, all my styling and pictures aren't displayed with this method. Is there a reason why? thanks

Comment: I'm not sure why the pictures wouldn't show, this just tells the browser to scroll/find the element with the ID of #something

Comment: I checked the errors in my console and placing the id in the url makes a majority of my content appear as a 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I figured it out. I don't need the "/". You just run the url and the id together. thanks

Comment: I have expanded the answer to give you more option on methods.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to make the answer stronger, please check updated answer. This will check the url for a scroll= param and it will scroll to that point but i recommend adding some validation in to make sure only 0-9 is being used in the `window.scoll()` because anything else will cause errors. I thought it would be nice for me to leave you to do a little yourself :p Happy coding!