# Ember advanced routing

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have my root url serving as a route for users. So `domain.com/danielvdm` will go to a profile. But I want to have a route to videos like this: `domain.com/video-title/v=15015kgha9`.

Is there a way in ember I can detect that the second level of this route starts with v= and then know that we're on the video route and not some subset of the user route?

Thanks

Comment: you can use javascript to get url parameters but i think the use might have to be `domain.com/video-title/?v=15015kgha9` using the `?` in order to get the url search/params.  One of my previous answers uses javascript to get search/url params if you want to look at that. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28467667/how-can-i-change-the-scrollbar-location-once-a-link-is-clicked/28467735#28467735 this will look for `/?scroll=something`. I'm sure you could take out the bits you need.

Comment: Can you share your current setup in a [bin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com)